# "double[] array = {1,2,3,4};" vs "double[] array = new double[]{1,2,3,4,};"

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

I have been programming for quite sometime and I came across something I never noticed before.

What is the difference between these two?

```
double[] nums = {1,2,3,4};
double[] nums2 = new double[]{1,2,3,4,};
```

They both compile and have the same properties. At first I thought that **nums2** could accept a `new int[]` and have integer values in it since its lower down in the hierarchy. But It actually didn't work.

Comment: no difference i believe

Comment: The difference is that you can only use the former syntax when declaring a variable. You can use the latter syntax anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The **first way** is just a **shortcut syntax to create and initialize an array** of the **second way**.

This is the only difference.

---

Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html